# Using a Variable as List Type in C#

Tags: c#, json, refactoring, generic-collections

I am currently using a list to handle a JSON string which works fine for one instance of this, as can be seen below. What I want to do is make these methods that handle the conversion completely generic so I can use them for multiple JSON strings.

This is a snippet of my current code as it stands.

> ```
> public class GetPerson
> {
>     public string fooName { get; set; }
>     public string fooAddress { get; set; }
>     public string fooPosition { get; set; }
> }
> public class GetPosition
> {
>     public string fooTitle { get; set; }
>     public string fooDepartment { get; set; }
>     public string fooSalary { get; set; }
> }
>
>     private static List<GetPerson> ConvertToList(string jsonString)
>     {
>         List< listJson = new List<JsonObject>();
>         listJson = (List<GetPerson>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GetPerson>>(jsonString);
>         return listJson;
>     }
> ```

This is just a quick sample but the `List<GetPerson>` is what I need to be generic so it can be reused, because as it stands the GetPosition will obviously not work with this, as I would want to be able to iterate through my code changing the type accordingly.

Is there a way I can assign a variable as a type? I saw another question about this but it didn't go into detail. Or is there another way that this could be achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Generics to help make the `ConvertToList` function reusable for different types

```
private static List<T> ConvertToList<T>(string jsonString)
{
    return (List<T>)JsonConverty.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(jsonString();
}
```

You can now call it using both `GetPerson` and `GetPosition` as the generic type.

```
var listOfPeople = ConvertToList<GetPerson>(personJson);
var listOfPositions = ConvertToList<GetPosition>(positionJson);
```

You can read more about Generics on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Also, if all that you want to do is to [de]serialize JSON, you might want to consider a third-party library for that like [JSON.net](http://james.newtonking.com/json), [Jil](https://github.com/kevin-montrose/Jil) or [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text), all of which have built in functions to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Awesome thanks for your answer. I knew about generic collections but was not aware how to correctly implement them. I am also utilizing Json.net to handle the conversion of the Json to a list.

Answer (score 1):

Very Simple. You just have to make ConvertToList() generic and pass the desired class as `Type Paramter` in ConvertToList()

```
private static List<T> ConvertToList<T>(string jsonString)
{
    var listJson = new List<JsonObject>();
    listJson = (List<T>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(jsonString);
    return listJson;
}

var personList = ConvertToList<GetPerson>(jsonString);
var positionList = ConvertToList<GetPosition>(jsonString);
```